# How to display mentiones users avatar in an embed discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a user info command, but I've run into a problem with displaying people's avatars. My command is supposed to respond to this: `&profile {user ping/user ID}`.

So, if you do `&profile @user#0001`, it will display the info of `user#0001`. If you do `&profile 123456789123456789`, it will display info about the user with ID `123456789132456`. If you do `&profile` without a mention, it will display info about you.

Whenever I run `&profile`, it posts the embed without problems. But, if I mention someone or put someone's ID, it crashes. This is my code:

```js
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "profile",
  description: "The bot will return the info about the user",
  execute(message, args) {
    let userinfoget =
      message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first()) ||
      message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    //var userinfoget = message.mentions.members.first();
    //var patter = message.author;
    //var randompatemote = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    if (!userinfoget) {
      userinfoget = message.author;
    }

    console.log(`User = ${userinfoget}`);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`User info`)
      .setColor("#DAF7A6")
      .setAuthor(`${userinfoget.tag}`, userinfoget.displayAvatarURL())
      .addFields({ name: `${userinfoget.tag}`, value: `Here will be the ID` });
    message.channel.send(embed);
  },
};
```

When I mention someone, it throws the error:

```
userinfoget.displayAvatarURL is not a function
```

The same thing happened if I put an ID. But if I put nothing behind the command (so it displays my info), it works. An example of what I'm trying to get is in the attachment.

[image: Example]

It displays in the embed correctly, but only if it displays mine, otherwise it crashes. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Use some try/catch blocks and some logging, and then come back and let us know what the crash is about.

Comment: The only thing I get is this:

userinfoget.displayAvatarURL is not a function

Comment: Then members.cache.get() and mentions.members.first() are not returning anything, or are not returning anything on time. The cache query is almost certainly asynchronous.

Comment: @Nathan Hawks I made a mistake when logging the userinfoget value, I've put it after the code that crashes the bot. Now I've moved it and it logs it in exactly the same form in all of the 3 cases (for example <@123456789123456789>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the error comes from this line:

```js
let userinfoget = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

`Guild.member()` method converts a `User` object to a `GuildMember` object, if possible.
`message.mentions.members.first()`, if defined, is already a `GuildMember` object.

All you need to do is change the aforementioned line with:

```js
let userinfoget = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.member(message.author)
```

You can remove the following line now:

```js
if (!userinfoget) {
    userinfoget = message.author
};
```

Comment: Nothing changed, I still get the "userinfoget.displayAvatarURL is not a function" error if I mention someone/put in someones ID @Jakye

Comment: no, it logs the same way for all 3 scenarios, for example <@123456789123456789>

Comment: @mkpanda `userinfoget` is a `GuildMember`, not `User`. `GuildMember` has no `displayAvatarURL` method. Instead, try: `userinfoget.user.displayAvatarURL()`

Comment: Now it works only if I ping someone or put their ID in there. For now I made it so my old code is executed only if it shows the info about the user that executed the command and the new code only if it shows info about someone else. It works, but it is really unefficient, so if there is any fix, I would be really happy :)

Comment: I've updated the code. Could you try again and tell me if you experience the same issue?  All you need to change is how you define `userinfoget`.